# Java reference to activity

Tags: java, android

i have non-Activity class QtAdMobBanner that store reference to main Activity (simplified code below), why reference that set once at initialization still valid after activity created/destroyed (ActivityLifecycleCallbacks still work)?

```
public class QtAdMobBanner implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private final Activity _activity;

public QtAdMobBanner(Activity activity) {
    _activity = activity;
    _activity.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}
...
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityCreated ");
}
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityPaused");
}
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityDestroyed!");
}
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityResumed!");
}
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivitySaveInstanceState!");
}
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityStarted!");
}
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("", "JAVA onActivityStopped!");
}
}
```

```
I         : JAVA onActivityPaused
I         : JAVA onActivityCreated
I         : JAVA onActivityStarted
I         : JAVA onActivityResumed
I         : JAVA onActivitySaveInstanceState
I         : JAVA onActivityPaused
I         : JAVA onActivityResumed
I         : JAVA onActivityStopped
I         : JAVA onActivityDestroyed
I         : JAVA onActivityPaused
I         : JAVA onActivityCreated
I         : JAVA onActivityStarted
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns of course, how without that i would ask question and write test output?

Comment: I somehow managed to completely miss that output block, my apologies

Comment: It's not that activity reference is somehow valid. Rather, you are registering your callbacks on the `Application` level, which is far more long-lived object than any activity in your app (because it, generally speaking, represents the app itself).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes, i misunderstand ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, it captures lifecycle events of all activities

Answer (score 0):

To reference an activity you should use a WeakReference (not a common variable) because it may be destroyed, and you should check if activity is still valid when you want to use it. Here you have an example using an AsyncTask that needs a reference to the activity https://riptutorial.com/android/example/14069/pass-activity-as-weakreference-to-avoid-memory-leaks

Check that onPreExecute in that example it does mActivity.get() what gets the real reference to the activity and before using it, there's a not null check.

Comment: Having to pass around `WeakReference<Context>` generally means that there's a lifecycle mismatch, and you should prefer to use event emission (observer pattern) instead of passing the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't call `unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks` (`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)`, passing your QtAdMobBanner object as the argument.

Comment: If you found this answer to be helpful, please upvote it and/or set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because that Activity is calling `new QtAdMobBanner(this)` somewhere -

and a new reference will be instanced `onCreate()`.

See [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Comment: Its Qt C++ Application for Android that uses JNI,  QtAdMobBanner object created at C++ side via Qt JNI wrapper ```new QAndroidJniObject("com/example/QtAdMobBanner", "(Landroid/app/Activity;)V", QtAndroid::androidActivity().object<jobject>());```